# translationInView not working

Tags: xcode, uigesturerecognizer

I used this code many times but in my current project it isn't working. Here is the error (third line):
 "No visible @interface for 'UIGestureRecognizer' declares the selector 'translationInView:'

and my simple code:

```
- (IBAction)panLayer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)pan{
if (pan.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
    CGPoint point = [pan translationInView:self.view];
    CGRect frame = self.settingsView.frame;
    frame.origin.y = self.layerPosition + point.y;
    if (frame.origin.y < 0) {
        frame.origin.y = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the UIPanGestureRecognizer that has UIGestureRecognizer as the parent class.

```
- (IBAction)panLayer:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)pan{
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was the mistake :)